# Data structure to group unique objects and support moving between groups maintaining uniqueness

Tags: data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure that supports this use case - there must be one out there!

A set of objects of type `T` can be stored in a `Group`, parameterised by the type `T`. A grouping has a `GroupIdentity` that uniquely identifies the group. Any `T` can only exist in one `Group`.

A management object, let's call it `GroupStore`, is capable of the following operations:

```
group(Set[T]) : GroupIdentity // Add or update a group and return its identity 
remove(Set[T]) // Remove the specified Ts from any existing groups
replaceOrMove(T1, T2) // Update any group that has T1 and replace it with T2. If T2 is already in a group the effect is that T1 is removed from its source group. Otherwise, T2 is created in T1's existing group.
getIdentity(T) : GroupIdentity
```

Some example test cases:

```
group(a, b, c)
= GroupIdentity(f98eh3)
getIdentity(b)
= GroupIdentity(f98eh3)
remove(b)
getIdentity(b)
= <empty>
group(a, b, c)
= GroupIdentity(f98eh3) // a and c already exist, so add b to the group and return the existing identity
group(a, d)
= GroupIdentity(f98eh3) // a already exists, so add d to the group 
move(b, e)
getIdentity(b)
= <empty>
getIdentity(e)
= GroupIdentity(f98eh3)
move(e, a)              // in effect this is a removal of e and adding a to the group that e existed in
getIdentity(e)
= <empty>
getIdentity(a)
= GroupIdentity(f98eh3)
group(x, y, z)
= GroupIdentity(e9g86z)
move(a, z)
getIdentity(a)
= <empty>
getIdentity(z)
= GroupIdentity(e9g86z)
```

I'm guessing this already exists...

Comment: "_Any T can only exist in one Group._" Did you mean any object of type `T` can be stored in at most one group? If so, the comment of `move` doesn't make sense. Otherwise, I don't get that sentence, since "_a Group, parameterised by the type T._"

Comment: Can you explain why `move` doesn't make sense?

Comment: "_Update all groups that have the T1 in a group_" There is only 1 group (or none) that contains `T1`. It doesn't make sense to talk about "all" when referring to a single group. Seems like "replace" would be a better name for the function.

Comment: Gotcha! Yes, much better, thanks. Thing is, it could replace _or_ move. These confusing semantics make me think this isn't the right solution, hence part of the original motivation for the question.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer what you mean.

Comment: I did. Can you explain what isn't clear?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you would solve this problem by using a nested collection, as in

```
Dictionary<TGroupKey, Dictionary<TItemKey, TItem>> collection;
```

Microsoft offers a [KeyedByTypeCollection Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyedbytypecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) which might prove useful.

You can enforce the "can only belong in one group" rule by also putting all of your items in a separate dictionary.

```
Dictionary<TItemKey, TGroupKey> itemIndex;
```

This dictionary will enforce the rule that you only allow the item to be added to the entire collection once.  To move it to a different group, remove it from both collections, add it to the new group, and put it back into the `itemIndex` dictionary.

When you use GroupBy in Linq, it produces an [`IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) as a result.

Comment: I apologize for the Microsoft-centric technologies, but it's what I know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92261/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-dan-gravell).